# why is R-square NOT well-defined for a regression without a constant term

Tags: statistics, matlab, regression, linear-regression

We often have a constant term in a linear regression such as, $y=\beta_1 x+\beta_0$. The $R^2$ or the coefficient of determination, is defined as $R^2=1-\frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}}$, where $SS_{res}$ and $SS_{tot}$ are residual sum of squares and total sum of squares. Let's say now we drop the constant term $\beta_0$, the above formula for calculating $R^2$ still works, or is it?

If we try this in Matlab, we receive a Warning that says, R-square and the F statistic are not well-defined unless X has a column of ones. What does "not well-defined" mean here? It seems okay.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the definition of the $R$ squared  statistic is based on the orthogonal decomposition of the total sum of squares, namely 
$$
SS_{total}=SS_{res}+SS_{reg} 
$$
dividing by the $SS_{total}$, you will get
$$
\frac{SS_{reg}}{SS_{total}} = \frac{SS_{total}}{SS_{total}} - \frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{total}} = 1 - \frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{total}} = R^2.
$$
Now, this decomposition is basically a consequence of the inclusion of the constant term $\beta_0$, hence from the first order condition you'll have $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{y}_i = 0$ which guaranties the orthogonality of $e$ and $\hat{y}$. A very good and elaborated answer you can find [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo).

Comment: In the answer from your link, why is $\bar{y}$ missed from the denominator of R0-sqaure? Isn't supposed to be $y_i-\bar{y}$?

Comment: SST is the SSreg for the null model, i.e.,  $y = \beta_0 + \epsilon$, thus if the null model do not includes intercept then the SST must be $\sum y_i^2$.

Comment: @V.Vancak I am wondering why you mentioned $\sum^n_{i=1} \hat{y_i}$. Isn't that the first-order conditions from OLS regression with a constant term, $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i(y_i - \hat{y}_i)=0$, guarantees the orthogonality of $e$ and  $\hat{y}_i$?